How to configure Python on Altair RapidMiner software?
I've installed Rapidminer studio on windows.I use Python on Jupyer notebook running on WSL. I installed the Python extension on Rapidminer then tried configuring Python path on Rapidminer software selecting virtualenwrapper option from dropdown of all scripting paths and mentioning WSL path of python.It is still showing python not configured properly.
 the problem pop up from the execute python object
 this is the screenshot what I said
I wanted to configure Python on WSL to Rapidminer but it did not work as per given wsl path even though I adjusted the windows system variables path with the wsl path as \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\shoun10\mlenv\bin\python.

Have you tried setting the package manager to specific python binaries?

You can also have a look at the official documentation around Altair RapidMiner and Python: https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/python/index.html
